# layout_weight and layout_gravity of Items within RecyclerView not working

Tags: android, xml

My purpose is to have the items of the RecyclerView aligned in the following manner:

- Both TextViews are aligned to the left,
- EditText is aligned to the right,
- First TextView takes 1/5th of the screen, 2nd TextView takes 3/5ths of the screen and EditText takes the last 5th of the screen.

However for some reason it's not working.

Here is the Layout for the item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:labelFor="@id/editVote"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editVote"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which is contained within a ViewPager in an activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

All items are added programmatically.

Despite my intentions, the end result decides to ignore both the attributes of `layout_weight` and `layout_gravity` as shown:

[image: Running the application]

Any extra information needed I will be happy to provide.

Comment: What's the root element of the list item layout?

Comment: A viewPager within an activity. I'll update the information.

Comment: ViewPagers don't take direct children. I mean, what is wrapping those three elements you have?

Comment: Post the complete layout file of your RecyclerView item.

Comment: @TheWanderer a LinearLayout as shown in the code above

Comment: @Sharj That's it for the RecyclerView Item, perhaps you want me to post the java code?

Comment: @Yokhen not the java code. Your item view layout file where you have your LinearLayout.

Comment: What are the attributes on the LinearLayout? The width needs to be `match_parent` for weights to do anything.

Comment: Oh my apologies, It must have cut off in the formatting, I'll fix it.

Comment: @TheWanderer my goodness, now I feel silly. `match_parent` was THE solution. Should I erase this question or ...

Comment: I'll just put it as an answer. Everyone makes silly mistakes, and this could help others.

Comment: if linearlayout's orientation is horizontal, under that layout start, end, left, right can't be used as value of layout_gravity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your LinearLayout root's width is `match_parent`, otherwise weights will do nothing:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ...
```